# MRTK (Hololens 2) Active pinch event with HID Joystick plugged into usb-c port

Tags: c#, hid, hololens, mrtk

I've been browsing through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/input/create-data-provider?view=mrtkunity-2021-05 trying to figure out how to fire off a pinch action with a hardware button plugged into the hololens 2.

The simple test I'm trying to build is when using the target selection demo, where you look at a target with your eyes, I want to be able to press the button plugged into the hololens, and active pinch with standard MRTK calls to destroy the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, HoloLens only supports the classes of USB-C devices listed in the following link:[HoloLens 2: Connect USB-C devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-connect-devices#hololens-2-connect-usb-c-devices), so it is better to check that the controller could be recognized as a USB HID Input device in the HoloLens first.

Besides, you can navigate to MRTK/Tools/RuntimeTools/Tools/ControllerMappingTool and open the ControllerMappingTool scene to determine button mapping for your controller. Usually, the controller that does not have a defined controller type will fall back to the generic controller type. If the active state of the button is displayed on the screen, you can try to use Unity API Input.GetButton to read data from inputs, or add a Generic Unity Controller in the Controllers Profile and map Select action to the button you want.